# Erro when install Igraph 0.7 on debian

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, igraph

I tried to install the python-igraph from:

`pip install python-igraph`

and

[https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph] `python setup.py build`

Both reported an error equal to this bug: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/468

After several failed attempts I had another erro:

Input: `sudo python setup.py build` or `sudo pip install python-igraph`

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:282: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.7.1-4' to '0.7.1.post4'
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating python_igraph.egg-info
writing python_igraph.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_igraph.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_igraph.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing python_igraph.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_igraph.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_igraph.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'python_igraph.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'python_igraph.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'python_igraph.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Build type: dynamic extension
Include path: /usr/local/include/igraph
Library path: /usr/local/lib
Linked dynamic libraries: igraph
Linked static libraries: 
Extra compiler options: 
Extra linker options: 
building 'igraph._igraph' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/edgeobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/edgeobject.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/random.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/random.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/bfsiter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/bfsiter.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/edgeseqobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/edgeseqobject.o
In file included from src/edgeseqobject.c:27:0:
src/convert.h:63:57: error: unknown type name ‘igraph_layout_grid_t’
src/convert.h:66:63: error: unknown type name ‘igraph_random_walk_stuck_t’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a copy of the C core of igraph installed in `/usr/local`, but that is not compatible with the version of the Python interface that you are trying to install. Judging from the output, you are installing `python-igraph 0.7.1-4`, which is compatible with igraph 0.7.1. So, either install the C core of igraph, version 0.7.1, or just remove all the igraph-related stuff from `/usr/local/include/igraph`, `/usr/local/lib` and probably `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` and then try again with `pip install python-igraph`. If you removed the C core from your machine, `pip install python-igraph` will try to download it and link to it when it compiles the Python interface.